# (Groovy @ 12.04) Error on: $ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the following command:

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 74, in <module> main()
File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 70, in main quiet=mot args.verbose
File "./src/catkin/bin/.../python/catkin/builder.py", line 494, in build_workspace_isolated number=index + 1, of=len(packages)
File "./src/catkin/bin/.../python/catkin/builder.py", line 315, in build_package build_catkin_package(path, package, spaces, options)
File "./src/catkin/bin/.../python/catkin/builder.py", line 219, in build_catkin_package run_command_colorized(cmake_cmd, build_dir, options['quiet'])
File "./src/catkin/bin/.../python/catkin/builder.py", line 121, in run_command_colorized stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in ___init___ errread, errwrite) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _executed_child raise child_exception)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions? Kernel is armv7l

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51746/(groovy-@-12.04)-error-on:-$-./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated---install/) by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-08**:
does ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make --install work? This will only work if you remove all non-catkin packages from the src folder

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-01-09**:
UPDATE:
It was an error linked to my other issue described in
[(Groovy @ 12.04) E: Package 'libtbb-dev' has no installation candidate](http://answers.ros.org/question/51742/groovy-1204-e-package-libtbb-dev-has-no-installation-candidate/)

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-01-09**:
HOWEVER:
Now that it is working, I am getting an error after installing Package 10 of 153, right after:
==> make -j2 in '/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/flann'
error: My Terminal Emulator is killing my ubuntu.img image connection, causing my androidVNC to shut down.

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-01-09**:
(Please note that the CPU Usage Monitor is way high during this part.)
Any suggestions to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make_isolated is still somewhat in beta status.

```
File "./src/catkin/bin/.../python/catkin/builder.py"
```

attempts to run a shell command like

```
cmake /path/to/somepackage -D...
```

This raises "No such file or directory". This could mean you do not have cmake installed, or the path given to cmake does not exist.
To debug further change File

./src/catkin/bin/python/catkin/builder.py

in build_catkin_package, make the following change:

```
-    run_command_colorized(cmake_cmd, build_dir, options['quiet'])
+    try:
+        run_command_colorized(cmake_cmd, build_dir, options['quiet'])
+    except OSError:
+        sys.stderr.write('Command failed: %s" % cmake_cmd)
+        raise
```

Run this again, this should give you the command that failed. Run this manually on the shell and find out what goes wrong. If you find this is a bug in catkin, create a ticket at https://github.com/ros/catkin and post what the command was in your case.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2